# Kubuntu 18.04 not login from SDDM but from tty

Tags: kubuntu, login, tty, session, sddm

I have installed Kubuntu 18.04 on my laptop (OMEN HP [17-w033dx
]) and today, just after enabling VT on the BIOS Setup and rebooting, Kubuntu  not login from visual (SDDM) as usual. I disabled VT but the issue persist.

If I switch to an alternative `tty` and start the X Server with the `startx` command, all works fine.

What would be the solution for this issue?

If you need some extra information, like logs or anything to deep on, just say the log file or command and I will post and edit of the post.

## EDIT

Complete `.xsession-errors` log file:
[.xsession-errors](https://pastebin.com/raw/ZFZbJKUb)

Comment: Maybe the output of `tail ~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: I've updated the question with a link to the `.xsession-errors` file content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review carefully several log files, I realize that the SDDM were putting its logs into the `/var/log/syslog`, so reviewing carefully this file, and after try several options, this lines were came up in front of me:

```bsh
systemd[1613]: /usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf:16: invalid variable name "export ANDROID_HOME", ignoring.
systemd[1613]: /usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf:17: invalid variable name "export PATH", ignoring.
systemd[1613]: /usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf:18: invalid variable name "export PATH", ignoring.
systemd[1613]: /usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf:19: invalid variable name "export PATH", ignoring.
systemd[1613]: /usr/lib/environment.d/99-environment.conf:20: invalid variable name "export PATH", ignoring.
```

So, I commented these lines inside the `/etc/environment` and everything went ok.

```bsh
export ANDROID_HOME=/media/my-user/ANDROID/SDK/sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

Finally I cut these configuration from the `/etc/environment` and pasted it inside the `/home/my-user/.profile` for a better configuration.

Just a few lines in a wrong config file of the system caused this disaster, :(